# Sigmas Problem ΣΣ i^2

Tags: measure-theory

How can i solve this?

$ΣΣ i^2=?$

both are from 1 to 4
And i is the variable

My Answer is 58.am i correct?

Comment: what are the variables of each sum?

Comment: i is the variable

Comment: i is the variable for both?

Comment: also, I believe you can do this short double sum by hand, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes.i is the variable for both.i just need to check the answer

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. What's the context of this expression? There has to be some mistake that leads up to it.

Comment: How did you get the answer 58? I also agree with Erik's answer.

Comment: @MobinaK $i$ cannot be the variable for both of the sums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the correct expression?
$$\sum_{i=1}^{4}\sum_{i=1}^{4}i^2$$
If so this is equal to
$$\sum_{i=1}^{4}(1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2) = \sum_{i=1}^{4}30 = 120$$

Comment: You should start one of the sums with $j$ or another letter.

Comment: I agree, I was just trying to stick with the notation Mobina K was using.

Comment: Ok. I definitely think that the he/she misread the question.

Comment: Sticking to **bad** notations is a **bad** idea. Do not use the same variable twice.